# Очистка строки от чисел preg_replace - удалить в конце и оставить внутри

Tags: php, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет! Уже много чего перепробовал, но не могу сделать очистку строки от чисел.

Задача следующая: есть массив

```
$strong  = array(
'тут 1 строка 100 \r\n тут 1 строка 230', 'тут 2 строка 350 \r\n тут 2 строка 190',
);
```

Массив может содержать разные числа внутри и в конце строк.

Надо сделать очистку с помощью регулярного выражение (делаю на php) чтобы он удалял все числа из конца строки и оставлял их внутри.

[ вот мой код ]

```
// запускаем цикл

for( $key=0; $key <=count($strong); $key++ ){

// добавляем знак [,] в каждой новой строке (из массива)
$value = preg_replace('/\r\n/', ',', $strong[$key]);

// удаление всех чисел из строк
$value_1 =  preg_replace('/|\d+|\s${,}/', '', $value);

// вывод строки
  echo $value_1.'<p>';

}
```

на выходе получаю

```
тут строка тут строка тут строка тут строка
```

а надо вот так

```
тут 1 строка [удалено - 100] тут 1 строка [удалено - 230] тут 2 строка [удалено - 100] тут 2 строка [удалено - 190]
```

Буду благодарен за идеи и мысли, по доработке кода :)

---

надо оставить числа внутри строки, а в конце удалить

Comment: а 1 и 2 - не являются числами?

Comment: @Manitikyl, речь о цифрах на конце строки

Comment: Может, вам надо [`preg_replace('~(*ANY)\s*\d+\h*$\R*~m', '', $strong)`](https://ideone.com/fE3aRF)?

Answer (score 1):

Люблю *велосипедики* делать, если я правильно понял, то вам подойдет такой вариант:

```
$strong  = [
    'тут 1 строка 100 \r\n тут 1 строка 230', 
    'тут 2 строка 350 \r\n тут 2 строка 190',
];

foreach ($strong as $key => $value) {
    $exp[] = preg_split('~\s.r.n\s~', $value);
}

foreach ($exp as $keys => $value)
{
    $dc[] = preg_replace_callback('~(\d)+$~is', function($m) {
        return '[удалено - '.$m[0].']';
    }, $value);
}

foreach ($dc as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $x => $y) {
        echo $y, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

В результате будет:

```
тут 1 строка [удалено - 100]
тут 1 строка [удалено - 230]
тут 2 строка [удалено - 350]
тут 2 строка [удалено - 190]
```

Answer (score 0):

На перле у меня заработало вот так:

```
@strong  = ("тrtgflok f 476873 rireoireiojf 100\n тут 1 строка 230", "тут 2 строка 350 \r\n тут 2 строка 190");                
foreach $sv(@strong) {                                                                                                                                                
    $sv =~ s/(.*?)(\d+)(\s?)(\r?\n)(.*?\d+?.*?)(\d+)/$1 $5/g;                                                                  
    print "$sv\n";                                                                                                             
}
```

Сильно не тестировал, потому что есть штуки (lazy matches, например, ".*?"), в полной работоспособности которых не в перле не совсем уверен.

Comment: Но язык не Perl

Comment: @Let'ssayPie Но регэкспы в том языке перловые (Preg). Регэкс сочинил, осталось его обернуть.

Comment: А вы сами тестировали регулярку?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie да. Не сильно - не пробовал с нелатиницей, например - но тестировал. А, как же не пробовал - там же строки русские. Ладно, скажем так, не пробовал с катаканой.

Comment: Подход не совсем правильный

Comment: @Let'ssayPie принимаю. Но будет ещё лучше, если дадите строки, на которых оно ломается.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81935/discussion-between-lets-say-pie-and-alexander-prokoshev).